# Randomly VPS down and no SSH access

Tags: ubuntu, vps

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 (32bit) LEMP SSD, 512MB VPS (Digital Ocean). Its all the time memory usage bellow 60% and CPU usage also normal. After every 2 or 3 days this VPS down and can't even connect via SSH. Every time I have to restart the VPS through the VPS provider reboot option. But VPS provider dashboard display this VPS up (on). It hosted, 2 WordPress sites (not have more than 600 daily visitors).

How do I diagnosis the issues for this matter?

Comment: Did you check if anything showed up in the log before you forced it to reboot?  When it's unreachable, does it reply to ping requests as usual?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't checked ping. But I use NewRelic, it shows server not reponding too. Could you please tell me how to check the log if I can't access via SSH?

Comment: I'm almost sure Digital Ocean gives you access to the files through their control panel.